# Laravel unable to get cookie after set

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I can set cookie, but I can't get cookie, please help.

```
use Cookie;  // use cookie

...

public function index() {
    $cookie = Cookie::forever('default_store', 1);
    $default_store = Cookie::get('default_store');
    print_r($cookie);
    // return 
            Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie Object (
           [name:protected] => default_store 
           [value:protected] => 1 
           [domain:protected] => 
           [expire:protected] => 1618241894 
           [path:protected] => / 
           [secure:protected] => [httpOnly:protected] => 1 )

    print_r($default_store);
    // return empty

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is Laravel 5, take a look at the documenation on using Cookies in the Requests section:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#cookies

It looks like a couple of possibilities:

1. You aren't using the Request so you aren't getting the cookies from the page at all BUT you are still setting it successfully.
2. Your route for this page may not be using the "web" middleware

Try these and see what happens. It could be something really simple.

If you're using an older version, the documentation is a nice place to start.

Comment: Don't worry, i've done that before too! If this answered/helped you with your question, please accept/upvote :)

Comment: Hi, after much research I am still quit lost, can you explain view vs respond? how do I pass a view in the controller with cookie set? so I can retrieve it in another view?

Comment: Hmm... I've never looked into using cookies myself (use sessions mostly, never had need for cookies) but you can check out this thread: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-set-a-cookie-with-laravel-5